# Problema con postgres y conexion a localhost en puerto 5432

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

tengo un problema con postgres, lo estoy usando en ubuntu y al tratar de iniciar el servidor local no me deja y me muestra el problema:

````
11:18:25: Error: Error connecting to the server: no se pudo conectar con el servidor: Conexión rehusada
    ¿Está el servidor en ejecución en el servidor «localhost» (127.0.0.1) y aceptando
    conexiones TCP/IP en el puerto 5432?```
````

Comment: ya verifico el firewall??

Comment: Que comando estás poniendo para que te retorne eso?

Comment: si verifique firewall, y no es ningun comando eso ocurre cuando abro postgresql desde pgadmin3, al intentar acceder al localhost

Comment: Te aseguraste que está corriendo el servicio de PostgreSQL?

Comment: ese es el problema el servicio se ejecuta pero no esta corriendo, cuando uso service postresql status me dice que falla en ejecutar algunas cosas y que el servidor esta activo pero no corriendo

Comment: puedes mostrar lo que te lanza, revisaste los logs?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, it was working for me.
in configuration /etc/selinux/config.

change SELINUX=enforcing for SELINUX=disabled

And restart SO

ref: https://uniwebsidad.com/foro/pregunta/432/como-solucionar-los-problemas-de-conexion-de-doctrine-con-postgresql-en-centos-7/

Comment: En español por favor, pues estás en SO en español

Comment: Si se ha configurado el pg_hba.conf, su postgresql.conf, su servicio postgresql esta corriendo y puede conectarse externamente a su base de datos postgreSQL, pero su aplicativo no logra conectarse por error de: Conexión rehusada el problema puede deberse a la seguridad que tiene linux para aplicativos externos por lo que la solución:
Sería colocar en disabled SELINUX para permitir la conexión de aplicativos a externos a través de IP a su servidor Linux.

Comment: esto debe ir en la respuesta por favor edita y deja la explicación pero en español